# How can I make a python package in nixos?

Tags: python, jupyter, nix, nixos

I'd like to use [jupyter-book](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyter-book/), but it's not available in nixpkgs. So I have to write a package. But jupyter-book depends on a number of packages that are also not in nixpkgs. And then I have to make sure that the binary `jupyter book` is available once the package is installed. So really it's all a big mess.

[This is what I have so far, but it's nowhere close to working.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/book-computational-literary-analysis/blob/master/flake.nix)

Really all I want to do is type `nix shell` then `jupyter book` and have everything work as expected. I'm baffled as to why this has become a total functional programming nightmare.

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/nix-community/poetry2nix -- It should be fairly straight forward to get jupyter book installed with poetry. This may give you the remaining bits...

Comment: I can't get jupyter-book installed with poetry, much less with poetry2nix.

Comment: How about contacting the Nixpkgs team to add the jupyter-book package? There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So [I've just opened an issue for that at nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/132686), but to be fair, that doesn't really get me closer to being able to use the software, since now I have two problems: packaging the software myself, and/or waiting for someone else to do it.

Comment: Just to note, adding a bounty does not make your question anymore on-topic. You need to provide a [mcve], not a link to an off-site resource with a vague statement that it doesn't work.

Comment: Just to note, "anymore" is the adverb, but when you refer to quantity, you should use "any more," i.e., two words instead of one.